# Docker push to AWS ECR issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

for couple of days I am facing an issue with pushing image from jenkins to ECR and restart service.

My Jenkins instance is hosted on EC2 instance via ECS. (it's built as docker image too).

What I want to do is to build image, login to ECR, push image there and restart service. Login to ECR is problematic:

1. when I do "unset AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" the
   "aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1" command is success but push
   image is stopped by "no basic auth credentials".
2. when I do not invoke "unset AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" I 
   can't even login to ECR.

I did a lot of googling and analysis but I can not find any answer. 
Any ideas what may cause the problem? Is it IAM setting or ecs-agent stuff?

Policy used to run jenkins task:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "GetAuthorizationToken"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
            "ecr:PutImage",
            "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
            "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
            "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/salesiq*",
            "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/comhub*",
            "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/ssrt*",
            "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/reveal*",
            "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/se-*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "EcrManagement"
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "ecs:cluster": [
                    "arn:aws:ecs:*:*:cluster/salesiq*",
                    "arn:aws:ecs:*:*:cluster/comhub*",
                    "arn:aws:ecs:*:*:cluster/ssrt*",
                    "arn:aws:ecs:*:*:cluster/reveal*",
                    "arn:aws:ecs:*:*:cluster/se-*"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Action": [
            "ecs:RunTask",
            "ecs:StartTask",
            "ecs:StopTask",
            "ecs:DescribeClusters",
            "ecs:DescribeServices",
            "ecs:ListClusters",
            "ecs:DescribeContainerInstances",
            "ecs:StopTask"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "EcsManagement"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "ecs:List*",
            "ecs:Describe*",
            "ecr:Describe*",
            "ecr:Get*",
            "ecr:Describe*",
            "ecr:List*",
            "cloudwatch:Get*",
            "cloudwatch:List*",
            "cloudwatch:Describe*",
            "ecs:UpdateService"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "EcsListing"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Does your build docker container has IAM permissions to use ECR ? Here are a couple of ECR policy example : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/RepositoryPolicyExamples.html

Comment: yes, those are all policies attached to role assigned as "Task role" to jenkins container.

awsiam-sauce
awsiam-sauce-the-sequel
cloudwatch-logging
dynamodb-access
ecr-ecs-policy
lambda-access
s3-access
sns-access
sqs-access

Comment: Would be interesting to double check the policies under `ecr-ecs-lambda` from the list above

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be missing is the command `docker login` command itself. Which is not mentioned in your question. So you need the following;

```
    aws ecr get-login --region region --no-include-email
```

and then you want to execute the output of the above command;

```
    docker login -u AWS -p password https://aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Alternatively you can run;

```
    $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)
```

and then

```
    docker push $ecr_repo:latest
```

Sample of bash scripts I am running in my pipeline;

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -ex

    # $branch: current git branch
    # $commit: hash of the current git commit
    # $ecr_repo: Self explanatory

    $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)
    docker pull $ecr_repo:latest
    docker build --cache-from $ecr_repo:latest -t image_name .
    docker tag image_name:latest $ecr_repo:$commit
    if [ "$branch" = "master" ]; then
      docker tag image_name:latest $ecr_repo:latest
      docker push $ecr_repo:latest
    fi
    docker push $ecr_repo:$commit
```

Comment: That's the response of  "aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email":


Error when retrieving credentials from container-role: Error retrieving metadata: Received non 200 response (400) from ECS metadata: {"code":"InvalidIdInRequest","message":"CredentialsV2Request: ID not found","HTTPErrorCode":400}

Comment: but when I do something like this:
"unset AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" I can login, but it's failing at push phase

Comment: Are you using Amazon ECS-optimized AMI for your container instances? Also, can you attach to your question the Trust Policy that is used by your role?